# C# MemoryCache - appending to a cached array

Tags: c#, performance, append, memorycache

I'm using a MemoryCache to store quite long byte arrays in it.
I'd like to update one of the entries, to be exact, append to that certain byte array.

The solution I've came up with for now, is quite ugly, and I'm pretty sure there must be a better one.

```
memoryCache.Set(key, (memoryCache.Get(key) as byte[]).Concat(anotherArray).ToArray(), cip);
```

Naturally, this is horrible, and on larger byte arrays, an `OutofMemoryException` is imminent.

I'd appreciate any answer that could help me make this prettier and more memory-friendly.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What is the constraint that is has to be one large byte array? Do you have the option to make it a list of smaller byte arrays (that way you are not copying large quantities of data to make new byte arrays.

Comment: Oh... And your ToArray() is redundant as the result of the Concat is an array. It may be creating an additional copy of the data briefly that you don't need which will only add to your memory problems.

Comment: Agree with @ColinMackay on storing a list of byte arrayws. What's more, aren't you afraid of race conditions here?

Comment: The only constraint is that I didn't think of using a List of byte arrays. :) Seems like a great idea, I'll get to reworking the code to use it. 

However, storing many smaller byte arrays in a list takes up less memory, as one big array? :O

Comment: @ColinMackay The ToArray(), however is needed for whatever reason, the concat creates an IEnumerable, not an array, and Visual Studio complains.

EDIT: No, it doesn't complain; I apologise, I remembered wrong.

Comment: @AntonGogolev Race conditions are handled just a few lines of code ahead, I just copied the most relevant part of the code.

Comment: @ColinMackay Thank you! Using a list made it much simpler to handle.